# shipping option is not showing on paypal review order page and update order button is not working

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, paypal-express

i am working on magento 1.8.0 i have configured paypal express checkout in my store. all goes in payment process until process reached to review order page. here it will not showing shipping method option and update order button is also not working and place order button is disabled. so can anyone help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the carriers you have is not correctly setting the allowed methods, so it can't be seen by Paypal. It must be a custom carrier thats not been written correctly.